# Most commonly occuring bi-personal endings?

Tags: morphology, second-lang-acquisition, frequency, polypersonalism

Let's say you had a language where all the possible combinations of person and number for both subject and object were marked by a single fusional morpheme. If you were writing a book teaching this language, in what order would you teach the endings? Latin books I've seen normally don't just throw the entire declension chart at you, instead teaching you typically the nominative and accusative of one declension first, then another, then later introduing the third and the other cases one by one. How should you go about this for a language like I describe?

Comment: Most likely you’d start out with the intransitive endings, then the most common subject endings (1s, 3s, 3pl) coupled with the most common object endings (3s, 3pl), then the rest after that. But anecdotally, in my high school Latin classes, we _were_ just given a whole declension with all the cases from the start. We weren’t learning Latin in order to be conversational, so it didn’t matter that we didn’t know all the endings off by heart but had to look them up – it was more important that we be aware of what cases there are in Latin.